# MediaElement.js - getting debug info

Tags: javascript, html, mediaelement.js

I'm creating an audio player with MediaElement.js, like this:

```
//button has been clicked, create new audio player and play
var audioElement = $('<audio>', {
    id : 'audioPlayer' + index,
    src : '/streamFriendFile',
    loop : 'loop',
    preload : 'none'
})[0];
$(row).append(audioElement);
new MediaElement(audioElement, {
    plugins : ['flash', 'silverlight'],
    pluginPath : 'http://localhost:3000/mediaelement/',
    flashName : 'flashmediaelement.swf',
    silverlightName : 'silverlightmediaelement.xap',
    pluginWidth : 0,
    pluginHeight : 0,
    audioWidth: 0,
    audioHeight : 0,
    startVolume: 0.8,
    //loop: true,
    //enableAutosize: false,
    //features : [],
    //timerRate : 250,
    success : function(mediaElement, domObj) {
        console.log('mediaElement success!');
        mediaElement.play();
    },
    error : function(mediaElement) {
        console.log('medialement problem is detected: %o', mediaElement);
    }
});
```

The error callback is immediately called, but it only contains the media element as an argument. This does not tell me what is wrong.

How can I get the actual error message so I can debug this issue?

Note that I'm only using the MediaElement core API, thus not the actual player (so I only include mediaelement.js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your MediaElement options (along with flashName, silverlightName, etc...) add `enablePluginDebug:true` and it should show debug errors on the screen. From the [API reference](http://mediaelementjs.com/#api) in the code example at right.

Other than that I don't believe they have any detailed error handling yet for that error object, from looking at the [github repo](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement) it seems to be a "to do" feature mentioned at the bottom (most likely a 2.2 feature).

Looks like you might have to figure out your own error handling for the time being.